# Why is $\mathbb{III} -2H\mathbb{II} +K\mathbb{I} = 0$ based on the fact that $\mathbb{III} = dN \cdot dN$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Why is $\mathbb{III} -2H\mathbb{II} +K\mathbb{I} = 0$ based on the fact that $\mathbb{III} = dN \cdot dN$ where $N$ is the unit normal to the surface?

Comment: That's just the Cayley-Hamilton theorem from linear algebra... (any operator $A$ on a $2$-dim vector space satisfied $A^2 - {\rm tr}(A)A + \det(A){\rm Id}=0$)

Comment: @IvoTerek Is there any way to show this without using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: With a 2-by-2 matrix, you can verify the equation directly by computation.